# ¿Cómo puedo alinear un ícono (elemento i) en el lado derecho del footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fuentes, icons

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html lang="es"> <head>     <meta charset="utf-8" />    <title>Revol INC.</title>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min"></script>    <script src="assets/js/send-email.js"></script> </head> <body>  <a href="inicio.html"><img src="images/logo-001.jpg" alt="" /></a>  <header>        <nav>           <ul>
                <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="que-hacemos.html">Â¿QuÃ© hacemos?</a></li>
                <li><a href="como-lo-hacemos.html">CÃ³mo lo hacemos</a></li>
                <li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>           </ul>   </header>   <section id="main">         <div class="main">          <div class="first">
                <p><center>Â¡Hola! Sigue nuestros <strong>proyectos</strong> a fondo y conoce mÃ¡s acerca de <strong><em>Revol INC.</em></strong> Â¡SÃ³lo deja tu email abajo! Es totalmente <strong><em>GRATIS</em></strong>.</center><p>
                <center><input type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email">
                <a href="inicio.html"><input type="submit" onclick="send()"></a></center>           </div>      </div>  </section> </body> <footer>     <p>Revol INC.&copy; Todos los derechos reservados. <strong>2018</strong></p>    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> </footer> </html>
```

CSS

```
body {  text-align: center;     font-size: 22px;    font-family: verdana;   color: white;   background: url(../../images/bck-001.jpg);  background-size: cover;     background-position: center;    margin: 0;  padding: 0; } p {   font-size: 18px;    line-height: 20px; } div p {    text-align: left; } img {   border-radius: 100%;    width: 100px;   height: 100px;  margin-top: 18px; } .main {     margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;     margin-top: 95px;   margin-bottom: 95px; } .first, .second, .third, .fourth {   background: rgba(50,50,50,.8);  padding: 20px;  border-radius: 2px; } input {   margin: 20px 10px 0 0;  padding: 10px;  border: 0;  border-radius: 2px; } input[type="email"] {     margin-top: 30px;    } input[type="submit"] {   background: rgba(247,38,53,1);  color: white;   margin-top: 50px; }
#msg {  margin: 20px 10px 0 0;  padding: 10px;  border: 0;  border-radius: 2px; } ol, ul {  list-style: none; } li {    display: inline-block;  padding: 5px; } a {     text-decoration: none;  color: white; } i {     position: relative;     float: right;   margin: 5px; } header {     margin-top: 20px;   background: rgba(247,38,53,.8);     border-radius: 2px; } footer {  background: rgba(50,50,50,.8);  padding: 1px;   border-radius: 2px; }
```

SCREENSHOT

[image: FÍSICO DE MI PROBLEMA]

Hola, soy un amateur en los códigos y quisiera saber como alinear el ícono de instagram con el texto del footer hacia la derecha. Agradezco su ayuda, saludos. Buen día geeks!

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Lo haré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que meterlo en un contenedor y y en un li, y al li le tienes que dar posición relative y lo posicionas a tu gusto. Si quieres que sea responsive tienes que reescribir tu codigo saludos.

```css
body {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: verdana;
            color: white;
            background: url(../../images/bck-001.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        div p {
            text-align: left;
        }

        img {
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 18px;
        }

        .main {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 95px;
            margin-bottom: 95px;
        }

        .first,
        .second,
        .third,
        .fourth {
            background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        input {
            margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        input[type="email"] {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background: rgba(247, 38, 53, 1);
            color: white;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        #msg {
            margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        ol,
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

        i {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        header {
            margin-top: 20px;
            background: rgba(247, 38, 53, .8);
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        footer {
            background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
            padding: 1px;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
        
        footer li {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            top: -50px;
            list-style-type: none;
            float: right;
        }
        
        footer .container {
            position: relative;
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Revol INC.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/send-email.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="inicio.html"><img src="images/logo-001.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="que-hacemos.html">Â¿QuÃ© hacemos?</a></li>
                <li><a href="como-lo-hacemos.html">CÃ³mo lo hacemos</a></li>
                <li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="first">

                <center>
                    <p>Â¡Hola! Sigue nuestros <strong>proyectos</strong> a fondo y conoce mÃ¡s acerca de <strong><em>Revol INC.</em></strong> Â¡SÃ³lo deja tu email abajo! Es totalmente <strong><em>GRATIS</em></strong>.</p>
                </center>

                <center><input type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email">
                    <a href="inicio.html"><input type="submit" onclick="send()"></a></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>Revol INC.&copy; Todos los derechos reservados. <strong>2018</strong></p>
        <div class="container">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram" style="color: #262626"></i></a></li>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :).